# Python : Spécial char in path name

Tags: python, char, decode, encode

I'm having a problem with python's script in eventghost: `eg.globals.test` is an external variable

```
eg.globals.test = "test♥.png"
```

**My script :**

```
Import Image

print eg.globals.test 

#test♥.png

picture = Image.open(eg.globals.test)
```

```
# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: test \u2665.png'
```

Python converts ♥ to `\u2665.png`. I've tried encode, decode, unicode functions but no effect.

Comment: Have you tried to add ``# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`` to the top of your script?

Comment: You've "tried encode, decode, unicode functions", okay, show us.

Comment: AFAIK you can't have special symbols on filenames...

Comment: @Kroltan You *can* have special characters in filenames. It *completely* depends on the OS. Some OS allow any unicode filename, other are pretty strict. Knowing which OS the OP is running could help...

Comment: Hmm indeed, but in general, cross-platform code (like Python is classicaly), should try to be as homogeneous as possible. I would recommend the OP to stick with `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` `_` `-` `.` since all OSs support these. As for the question itself, I can't help...